# Question regarding downvotes on asked question

Tags: discussion

I'm new here. I was having some trouble with a bit of code and I've read a lot of advice on here though web searches so I thought this might be a good place to come for help with my particular issue.  However, it's not feeling that way because I got down voted, apparently because some other user didn't like that I made a coding joke (that I couldn't get RAID, a bug spray, on the bug in my code.)

I can understand if folks don't get the joke, but I feel that intentionally down voting the question so that they are less likely to get an answer is a pretty hostile "retaliation" for it.

I am just wondering if that is the norm of the way this "community" "helps" folks, because if it is, then I'm going to find somewhere else as this clearly isn't my kind of "forum".  I'm an old school coder from the late 80's and back then making jokes about code and being friendly to, at the time rare, fellow coders was kind of a thing. ~shrug~

Comment: Well you may confuse that someone edited out your _joke_ (as noise), with that single downvote are inherently coupled actions. Your question contains a lot of prose already, that doesn't make it clearer what you're asking about actually.

Comment: We like humor. But it's difficult to get right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go

Comment: The joke was probably removed for being "too localized".

Comment: And please don't call SO a "forum". We can be quite serious about that.

Comment: Humor *is* hard to get right, especially in an international forum (not in the sense you decry, Jongware). I actually knew what RAID was in the extermination sense but my first thought here would have been redundant drive arrays. Would you know what a zero weed wand was? Or a Hill's Hoist, or a thong (in the Australian sense, which I think may be a flip-flop elsewhere)? Nothing's quite so depressing as having to explain your humour :-)

Comment: Of all the possible reasons a "debug my code" question could be downvoted, a joke is the least likely one.

Answer (score 14):

You assume a lot of things that are not correct or misunderstood from either the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Notice that [Stack Overflow is not a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/158100)

In general we are not here to help anyone. The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a collection of (high) quality questions and answers that are voted up and down based on their merits. Notice how there is no social element in that, nor retaliation as such.

Down voting is a privilege for users with at least [125 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), so they are a little bit familiar with how this site works. Down voting is done when posts are:

- not useful, and/or
- not well researched, and/or
- not clear

Your particular question got probably down voted because you effectively dropped a pile of code with some bug in it that some members found hard to debug because neither they nor you could get it to work in a fiddle.
To compensate you provided a lot of context that didn't really help either.

In the help center you'll find [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and advice on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you strip down all that code to the bare minimum to demonstrate your issue in a fiddle, reduce the text to be to the point, you should be fine.

Keep in mind that questions and answers are meant for future visitors that experience the same issue. For that to work the questions need to be clear. The answers might help you (indicated by accepting one of them) but foremost other visitors.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've apparently misunderstood the purpose of this site. Thank you for clearing that up.  I would suggest however, that ya'll edit the site listing and wiki posting regarding the purpose of Stack Overflow as it explicitly states: "It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts-Exchange." (emphasis on open) - when it is not as I understand your reply. Aka - The intent here is not to answer questions from coders, but rather a collection of select questions with voted answers. Such distinction should be noted so others do not wander in as I did.

Comment: It is very open. Everybody can ask a question, suggest an edit and read answers. You don't need an account to use the information we gathered here which was one of the most annoying *features* of EE. And we still need coders to ask questions but not just any question. That is where the SE network is very different and moderated for by the community.